# How to vectorize loop operating on 3 channel OpenCV Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, vectorization

I'm trying to improve performance in some code operating on a 3 channel OpenCV matrix. 
The loop looks something like this:

```
unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(img_input.data); // 3 channel rgb
unsigned char *output = (unsigned char*)(img_output.data); // 1 channel

for(int j = 0;j < img_input.rows;j++){
    for(int i = 0;i < img_input.cols;i++){
        unsigned char b = input[NUMCOLS * j + 3 * i ] ;
        unsigned char g = input[NUMCOLS * j + 3 * i + 1];
        unsigned char r = input[NUMCOLS * j + 3 * i + 2];
        output[NUMCOLS * j + i] = // some operations with r g and b here
    }
}
```

Now gcc can't vectorise this

```
complicated access pattern
```

Which isn't too surprising. It vectorises ok if I have 2 channel, as it seems GCC looks for multiples of 2 in the loop index increment when vectorising.

Question: Is there a way to vectorise this loop that isn't just separating the input matrix into three separate matrices ?

Thanks.

Comment: first: try to **avoid** all such per-pixel loops, they're slow, error prone , and defeat the purpose of using a optimized, high-level library. then - what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm simply trying to threshold a 3 channel image. But CV::threshold only works on 1channel mat and too much information is lost converting to grayscale, CV::inRange doesn't do what I need (checking a condition on all 3 channels rather than any 3). Splitting the matrix, than performing 3 thresholds and joining them is too slow (slower than my loop)

Comment: if you got the same threshold value for all 3 channels, or using OTSU, threshold will still work (fast) on multi-channel images

Comment: Oh really ? The doc says 'input array, single channel'. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @y300 you say "Splitting the matrix, than performing 3 thresholds and joining them is too slow (slower than my loop)". Are you using a library function (cv::split) to do the splitting or some other method?

Comment: I've been using cv::split. I'll try and update soon with actual timings. Thanks for your time.